# Recursion Vs Iteration - When to use one over the other

Tags: for-loop, recursion, iteration

I am currently in my 2nd year of Computer Science degree and was studying  for my final. One of the topics were Iteration vs. Recusion, and this is all it said:

> The decision whether to use recursion or iteration should be based on the nature of, and
>   your understanding of, the problem you are trying to solve. The rule of thumb is to use whichever
>   approach can best develop an intuitive solution that naturally mirrors the problem. If an
>   iterative solution is obvious, use it. It will generally be more efficient than the recursive option.

However, I believe there is a more complex anwser when it is better to use each.  There has to be a give and take when you are talking performance.

If recurison uses to much memory within your program while the for loop may be a little bit slower, I know there is cases where each may be more benefical. From my understanding For Loops would be more benefical then recurison.

Intrested to hear other peoples thought.

Comment: I believe your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Recursion+Vs+Iteration

Comment: yes, there is give and take. If an iterative solution is obvious, use it. It will generally be more efficient than the recursive option. this implies, and it generally is true, that recursive solution is often easier to come by.